# Listview with custom adapter for cart activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-listview, adapter

I am using an ArrayList of Products to generate a ListView from a custom adapter for cart activity. Everything is working, except that I have to return to the activity three times before the items display. I am calling on an xml with ListView listed below RelativeLayout. Apologies for the messy code, I am still learning android. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Cart.java:

```
public class Cart extends AppCompatActivity {

private String user;
static final String TAG = "";
static ArrayList<Product> cartItems = new ArrayList<>();
ProductAdapter adaptCart;
ListView listView;
static int cartSize = 0;
Menu menu;
float shipCost = 15;
float tax = (float)0.07;
float taxRate = (float) 0.07;
TextView subTotal;
TextView shipping;
TextView taxes;
TextView cTaxes;
TextView totals;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
    user = MainActivity.currentAccount.getUsername();
    if(user == null || user.equals("Guest")) {
        shipCost = (float)0.00;
        tax = (float)0.00;
    }
    if(user != null && !(user.equals("Guest"))) {
        new getCartIcon().execute();
        //cartItems = new ArrayList<>();
        if(getCartNumber() != cartItems.size()) {
            cartSize = ProductAdapter.getCartSize();
            new refreshCartIcon().execute();
        }
        if(cartItems == null || cartItems.size() != getCartNumber()) {
            new returnCartItems().execute();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "cartItems size: " + String.valueOf(cartItems.size()));
        Log.d(TAG, "cartNumb size: " + getCartNumber());

        if(getCartNumber() == cartItems.size()) {
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_cart_view);
            adaptCart = new ProductAdapter(Cart.this, 0, cartItems);
            adaptCart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if(listView != null) {
            adaptCart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setAdapter(adaptCart);
        }
        //listView.notifyAll();
        }
    //}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_login){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Button logB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logB);
        logB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText user_Name, user_Pass;
                String password, username;
                user_Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_username);
                user_Pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
                password = user_Pass.getText().toString();
                username = user_Name.getText().toString();
                MainActivity.currentAccount.setPassword(password);
                MainActivity.currentAccount.setUsername(username);
                new userLog().execute();
            }
        });
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_register) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        Button logB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logR);
        logB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText user_First, user_Last, user_Email, user_Name, user_Pass;
                String first, last, email, password, username;
                user_First = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_firstName);
                user_Last = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_lastName);
                user_Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);
                user_Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_username);
                user_Pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
                first = user_First.getText().toString();
                last = user_Last.getText().toString();
                email = user_Email.getText().toString();
                password = user_Pass.getText().toString();
                username = user_Name.getText().toString();
                MainActivity.currentAccount.setFirst_name(first);
                MainActivity.currentAccount.setLast_name(last);
                MainActivity.currentAccount.setEmail(email);
                MainActivity.currentAccount.setPassword(password);
                MainActivity.currentAccount.setUsername(username);
                new userReg().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_cart) {
        new getCartIcon().execute();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cart.class));
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        new getCartIcon().execute();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Search.class));
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_account) {
        new getCartIcon().execute();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountActivity.class));
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_about_us) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);
    }

    if (MainActivity.currentAccount != null && id == R.id.action_logout) {
        MainActivity.currentAccount.setFirst_name("Guest");
        MainActivity.currentAccount.setLast_name("");
        MainActivity.currentAccount.setEmail("");
        MainActivity.currentAccount.setPassword("");
        MainActivity.currentAccount.setUsername("Guest");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUser(MainActivity.currentAccount);
        new getCartIcon().execute();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class getCartIcon extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String tempUser = user;
    int cartNum = 0;
    float tempTotal;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        subTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_subTotal);
        shipping = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_shipping);
        totals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_total);
        taxes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_taxes);
        cTaxes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_taxes);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        if(tempUser != null) {
            try {
                Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
                String queryString = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE `User_Name` = '" + tempUser + "'";

                PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
                //st.setString(1, tempUser);

                final ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(queryString);

                while (result.next()) {
                    try {
                        tempTotal += result.getFloat("Price");
                        //skus.add(result.getInt("SKU"));
                    } catch(SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    cartNum++;
                    //setTotal(result.getFloat(String.valueOf("Price")));
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        String taxation = "Taxes @ %" + String.valueOf(taxRate);
        getCartItems(cartNum);
        subTotal.setText(String.format("%.2f", Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(tempTotal))));
        if(tempTotal == 0) {
            shipCost = 0;
        }
        shipping.setText(String.format("%.2f", Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(shipCost))));
        tax = tempTotal * tax;
        cTaxes.setText(taxation);
        taxes.setText(String.format("%.2f", Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(tax))));
        totals.setText(String.format("%.2f", Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(tempTotal + shipCost + tax))));
        //new returnCartItems().execute();
        //setTotal(tempTotal);
        setCartNumber(cartNum);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

public class refreshCartIcon extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String tempUser = user;
    int cartNum = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        if(tempUser != null) {
            try {
                Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
                String queryString = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE `User_Name` = '" + tempUser + "'";

                PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
                //st.setString(1, tempUser);

                final ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(queryString);

                while (result.next()) {
                    cartNum++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        getCartItems(cartNum);
        setCartNumber(cartNum);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

public class returnCartItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String tempUser = user;
    Product product = null;
    ArrayList<Product> tempItems = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> skus = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        if(tempUser != null) {
            if ((getCartNumber() > 0 && cartItems == null) ||
                    (cartItems.size() != getCartNumber())) {
                try {
                    Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
                    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE `User_Name` = '" + tempUser + "'";
                    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
                    final ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(queryString);
                    while (result.next()) {
                        try {
                            skus.add(result.getInt("SKU"));
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
                    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM Inventory";
                    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
                    final ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(queryString);
                    while (result.next()) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < skus.size(); i++) {
                            if (skus.get(i) == result.getInt("SKU")) {
                                product = new Product();
                                product.setProduct_name(result.getString("Name"));
                                product.setSKU(result.getInt("SKU"));
                                product.setProduct_dept(result.getString("Department"));
                                product.setProduct_desc(result.getString("Description"));
                                product.setPrice(result.getFloat("Price"));
                                product.setProduct_qty(result.getInt("Quantity")-(result.getInt("Quantity")-1));
                                product.setProduct_img(result.getString("Image"));
                                tempItems.add(product);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setCartItems(tempItems);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

public void setCartItems(ArrayList<Product> cartItems) {
    this.cartItems = cartItems;
}

public class userLog extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String queryResult = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
            if(conn != null) {
                queryResult = "Successfully connected!";
                Login.login(MainActivity.currentAccount, conn);
            }
            else {
                queryResult = "Error in connection";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setUser(MainActivity.currentAccount);
        //getData.setText(queryResult);
        new getCartIcon().execute();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

public class userReg extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String queryResult = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
            if(conn != null) {
                queryResult = "Successfully connected!";
                Register.register(MainActivity.currentAccount, conn);
                conn.close();
            }
            else {
                queryResult = "Error in connection";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setUser(MainActivity.currentAccount);
        //getData.setText(queryResult);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

public void getCartItems(int cart) {

    MenuItem cartMenuItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
    if (cart == 0) {
        cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart0);
    }
    if (cart == 1) {
        cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart1);
    }
    if (cart == 2) {
        cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart2);
    }
    if (cart == 3) {
        cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart3);
    }
    if (cart == 4) {
        cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart4);
    }
    if (cart == 5) {
        cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart5);
    }
    if (cart > 5) {
        cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart5plus);
    }
    if (cart > 10) {
        cartMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.cart10plus);
    }
}

public void setUser(Account acct) {
    String aloha;
    if(acct.getFirst_name() != null) {
        aloha = "Welcome, " + acct.getFirst_name() + "!";
    }
    else {
        aloha = "Welcome, Guest!";
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_hello);
    textName.setTextSize(22);
    textName.setText(aloha);
}

public void setCartNumber(int cartSize) {
    this.cartSize = cartSize;
}

public static Integer getCartNumber() {
    return cartSize;
}

public static ArrayList<Product> getCartList() {
    return cartItems;
}
}
```

ProductAdapter.java:

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<Product> products;
ArrayList<Product> cartItems;
Product product;
Menu menu;
static Integer size;
static Integer cartSize;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
static View vi;
String money = "$";
String dept = "Dept: ";
String qty ="Qty: ";
static String URI;


public ProductAdapter(Activity activity, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Product> product) {
    super(activity, textViewResourceId, product);
    try {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.products = product;
        setCartItems(products);
        new getCartCount().execute();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationActivity());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return products.size();
}

public Product getItem(Product position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView product_name;
    public TextView product_desc;
    public TextView product_dept;
    public TextView product_price;
    public TextView product_qty;
    public ImageView product_img;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    vi = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(cartItems.size() == getCount()) {
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cart_items, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.product_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
                holder.product_dept = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_dept);
                holder.product_desc = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_desc);
                holder.product_price = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
                holder.product_qty = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.product_qty);
                holder.product_img = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                vi.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }
            Button remove = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.remove_btn);
            URI = "http://www.michaelscray.com/Softwear/graphics/";
            URI += products.get(position).getProduct_img();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(URI + products.get(position).getProduct_img());
            holder.product_name.setText(products.get(position).getProduct_name());
            holder.product_desc.setText(products.get(position).getProduct_desc());
            holder.product_dept.setText(dept + products.get(position).getProduct_dept());
            holder.product_price.setText(money + String.valueOf(products.get(position).getPrice()));
            holder.product_qty.setText(qty + String.valueOf(products.get(position).getProduct_qty()));
            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(URI).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.product_img);
            setProduct(getItem(position));

            remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //do something
                    new removeCartItem().execute(); //or some other task
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return vi;
}

public class removeCartItem extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String tempUser = MainActivity.currentAccount.getUsername();
    Product updateCart = getProduct();
    ArrayList<Product> cartItems = getCartItems();
    ArrayList<Product> cartUpdate = Cart.getCartList();
    Integer cartNumber = Cart.getCartNumber();
    Integer tempSKU = updateCart.getSKU();
    String queryResult = "";

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)  {

        if(tempUser != null && !(tempUser.equals("Guest"))) {
            try {
                Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
                String queryString = "DELETE FROM `Orders` WHERE `User_Name` = '"+tempUser+"' AND `SKU` = '"+tempSKU+"'";
            /*  Insert User_Name, SKU, Price, and Shipped   */
                PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
                st.executeUpdate();
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                queryResult = "Database connection failure!\n" + e.toString();
            }
            cartItems.remove(updateCart);
            cartUpdate.remove(updateCart);
            setCartSize(cartNumber-1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Removed item: " + tempSKU + " from your cart!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

public class getCartCount extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String tempUser = MainActivity.currentAccount.getUsername();
    int cartNum = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        if(tempUser != null) {
            try {
                Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
                String queryString = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE `User_Name` = '" + tempUser + "'";

                PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
                //st.setString(1, tempUser);

                final ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(queryString);

                while (result.next()) {
                    cartNum++;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        setCartSize(cartNum);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    }
}

private void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

private Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

private void setCartItems(ArrayList<Product> cartItems) {
    this.cartItems = cartItems;
}

private ArrayList<Product> getCartItems() {
    return cartItems;
}

private void setCartSize(Integer size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public static Integer getCartSize() {
    return size;
}


}
```

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until [no code can be removed while still running into the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think that I have reduced it as much as I can without affecting my other classes. Everything with the cart is working as it should, it just takes 3 times (going to the cart and pressing back) for the listview to populate

Comment: I was able to resolve this by:  `try {  cartItems = new returnCartItems().execute().get();  } catch (Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace();  }`

Comment: I suggest you write that up as a self-answer for others to vote on and more easily recognize when searching.